# MenuItemDefinition Order

Tags: sorting, asp.net-core, navigation, aspnetboilerplate

I'm getting started with ASP.NET Boilerplate where I am using the free start-up template of ASP.NET Core Multi Page Web Application.

My question is regarding the left hand navigation bar. I have the `NavigationProvider` in my project where the abstract class is implemented. I have been testing out some of the properties available in the `MenuItemDefinition`, specifically the `order` and `isVisible`. My expectation was that I could set both the `order` and `isVisible` properties and that this would show in the application when running. I don't however see any of these properties actually being used to either set the order of the menu items or control their visibility.

For the order property I updated the Default.cshtml of the `SideBarNav` component to implement an `OrderBy` so I can get the correct order. This works but I'm not sure if this is the recommended approach.

Is it correct that setting the order when adding a `MenuItemDefinition` doesn't actually have any consequence to the running application and that this property is here with the expectation that I implement the behavior as I've done in the Default.cshtml?

My reason for wanting to control the order this way rather than by just the order the items are added is related to creating different modules that each have their own NavigationProviders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it correct that setting the order when adding a MenuItemDefinition doesn't actually have any consequence to the running application and that this property is here with the expectation that I implement the behavior as I've done in the Default.cshtml?

Yes, the templates (as of v5.2.0) do not use nor implement ordering of user menu items.

I suggest implementing an extension method to easily change the ordering across the project.

```cs
public static IOrderedEnumerable<UserMenuItem> OrderByCustom(this IEnumerable<UserMenuItem> menuItems)
{
    return menuItems
        .OrderBy(menuItem => menuItem.Order)
        .ThenBy(menuItem => menuItem.DisplayName);
}
```

**Regarding versions**: You are using **v5.1.x and below**. As of v5.2.0, the template has been migrated to use AdminLTE 3 instead of AdminBSB for the MVC UI, so the following changes are incompatible.

## v5.2+

I have submitted a PR to implement the ordering: [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template#510](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/pull/510)

```cs
var orderedMenuItems = Model.MainMenu.Items.Where(x => x.IsVisible).OrderByCustom().ToList();
```

```cs
var subMenus = Model.Items.Where(x => x.IsVisible).OrderByCustom().ToList();
```

Files changed:

- Web.Mvc/Views/Shared/Components/SideBarMenu/Default.cshtml
- Web.Mvc/Views/Shared/Components/SideBarMenu/_MenuItem.cshtml

## v5.1.x and below

Note that you should change in 3 places (corresponding to 3 nesting levels) in Default.cshtml.

```cs
@foreach (var menuItem in Model.MainMenu.Items.OrderByCustom().ToList())
```

```cs
@foreach (var subMenuItem in menuItem.Items.OrderByCustom().ToList())
```

```cs
@foreach (var subSubMenuItem in subMenuItem.Items.OrderByCustom().ToList())
```

File changed:

- Web.Mvc/Views/Shared/Components/SideBarNav/Default.cshtml

Comment: That's excellent. My worry was that I had missed something or was using it incorrectly. Your response has answered my query, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! If you are still getting started, then I suggest starting from scratch with v5.2+ so that you can take advantage of subsequent enhancements.